# return exit code with is_eager option in python click

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-interface, python-click

I am using click framework.I want to return version and exit code when I run python hello.py --version. Currently my code is like this.

```
import click
def print_version(ctx, param, value):
    if not value or ctx.resilient_parsing:
        return
    click.echo('Version 1.0')
    return 1
    ctx.exit()

@click.command()
@click.option('--version', is_flag=True, callback=print_version,
              expose_value=False, is_eager=True)
def hello():
    click.echo('Hello World!')

hello()
```

```
$ python hello.py --version
    Version 1.0
    Hello World!
```

I am expecting an output like this:

```
$ python hello.py --version
    Version 1.0
    1
```

Comment: If you would change the code in the `hello()` function to `click.echo(1)` you will get your expected output. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: actually I want my eager function to return an exit code. in this case, i want print_version to print the version and return and exit code without invoking hello()

Comment: I added a answer. Let me know if this helped ツ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is that you are returning from your function before the exit statement is called. So it never gets ran. You don't need the return statement here. This code should work:

```
import click

def print_version(ctx, param, value):
    if not value or ctx.resilient_parsing:
        return
    click.echo('Version 1.0')
    ctx.exit(0)

@click.command()
@click.option('--version', is_flag=True, callback=print_version,
              expose_value=False, is_eager=True)

def hello():
    click.echo('Hello World!')

hello()
```

This will only output `Version 1.0` and than will exit with the exit code `0`. You can change the exit code you want to have to any you want in `cox.exit(YOUR_EXIT_CODE)` although you probably would want to use 0 as the exit code for this.

If you want to check the exit code you can execute your program and than run a extra command in your unix-based shell to get the exit code of the last command executed:

```
python3 FILE_NAME.py --version
echo $?
```

Comment: How to retrieve this exit code later? When I write  ctx.exit(1), it still doesnt print 1. is there a way to retrieve the exit code in a test?

Comment: Yes the exit code is normally not printed. If you want to check with which exit code a program exists just run the python code in a shell how you normally would do with `python3 FILE_NAME.py --version`. After it has executed type `echo $?` this will output the exit code of the last command executed in your shell. This should work with the most unix-based shells.